# VB6 IP4 - Calculate Net Mask (Long) from Number of Bits

Tags: vb6, performance, ip-address, bit-manipulation, cidr

Given input of 0 to 32, representing the number of one-bits in an IP4 network mask (corresponding to a CIDR block size as in /19), what's

1. An elegant way to turn that into a four-byte long net mask
2. A fast way way to turn that into a four-byte long net mask

**Prototype:**

```
Function NetMaskFromBitCount(BitCount As Long) As Long
   'Logic here '
End Function
```

Notice this is complicated by the fact that VB6 doesn't do unsigned, so regular math tricks often don't work. If `(Number And &H80000000)` is nonzero, then `Number \ 2` will NOT be the same as a SHR operation.

I've come up with a few ways, but I don't think they're elegant, and they're probably not that fast.

One idea I had is to strategically use the CopyMemory API, which is VERY fast. I've solved some signed/unsigned Long problems in the past by just blatting the Long into a Byte(0 To 3) and working with each portion as needed.

Since I'm also working with the inet_ntoa() and inet_addr() Windows API functions and they return the IP serial number in reverse byte order, a solution that returns the bytes in reverse order is great (I already have a function to flip the byte order if needed, but avoiding it would be nice, too).

**Examples:**

```
Input = 2
Output = -1073741824 (&HC0000000)
Alternate Output = 12 (&HC0, reverse byte order)

Input = 19
Output = -8192  (&HFFFFE000)
Alternate Output = 14745599 (&H00E0FFFF, reverse byte order)
```

Working solutions are good, but ELEGANT or FAST is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The things people do with VB6.

Comment: The way your last sentence is worded, it sounds like the ELEGANT or FAST solutions don't have to work!? I'm sure that's an oversight, but just in case can I proffer `Output = 0&`. Sure, it might not work in *every* case, but just feel the elegance and speed! :)

Comment: Let me rephrase. Working solutions are not enough. Working and ELEGANT or FAST is what I'm looking for! <big tongue sticking out>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function NetMaskFromBitCount(ByVal lBitCount As Long) As Long
    If lBitCount > 0 Then
        NetMaskFromBitCount = -1 * 2 ^ (32 - lBitCount)
    End If
End Function
```

Had to make this param `ByVal`!

And the test goes here:

```
Debug.Assert NetMaskFromBitCount(19) = &HFFFFE000
Debug.Assert NetMaskFromBitCount(2) = &HC0000000
Debug.Assert NetMaskFromBitCount(32) = &HFFFFFFFF
Debug.Assert NetMaskFromBitCount(0) = 0
```

Comment: Ooh. I kept thinking of the first bit as a problem. But this solution observes that all the masks are negative (have the first bit set) except for input 0, and are in fact the negative powers of two. Very interesting. I should have listed all the values and I would have instantly seen this! Maybe not so fast—if I recall, the power operator in VB isn't the fastest in the world. But very simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

You only have 32 possible inputs, so my guess is the fastest solution will be a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Counting_.271.27_bits_in_a_series_of_bytes) referencing all 32 outputs from an array. It won't win points for elegance. Warning: [air code](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2005/02/27/56126.aspx)

```
Function DoIt(ByVal Input As Long) As Long  
  Static lArray() As Long  
  Static bInitialised As Boolean   
  If Not bInitialised Then   
    ReDim Preserve lArray(0 To 31)   
    lArray(0) = 0   
    lArray(1) = &H80000000    
    lArray(2) = &HC0000000    
    ' etc... '  
    bInitialised = True 
  End If
  DoIt = lArray(Input)  ' for bonus marks raises an error on illegal input ' 
End Function
```

If you want something more general, VBSpeed has a long-standing open competition for [fast VB6 left-shifts](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftLeft.htm).

- Here's the current winner [`ShiftLeft04`](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/download/modShift_Paul.zip) which uses some horrendous, sorry I mean brilliant, tricks to get *inline assembler* in VB6. You'll laugh, you'll cry, you'll scream in terror...
- The current runner-up [ShiftLeft06](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftLeft.htm#ShiftLeft06) is about 200 lines of all-native VB6. Takes 1.3 times longer, but still quick.

Comment: VB6 doesn't allow array constants. What would you suggest is the best way to load the array for speed? A static variable could help, or an Init() that loads the variable once, but that becomes more clunky. Also, the shiftright stuff is really interesting. I presume you're suggesting something like Not(&HFFFFFFFF SHR BitCount)?

Comment: Or, is there a corresponding ShiftLeft, which would be simpler:
&HFFFFFFFF SHL (32-BitCount)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VB6, but here is how I would do it in .Net

```
    Const allBroadcast As Integer = Integer.MaxValue ' = 2,147,483,647
    Dim mask As Integer
    'three examples
    mask = allBroadcast << (32 - 24) '/24
    mask = allBroadcast << (32 - 16) '/16
    mask = allBroadcast << (32 - 8) '/8
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too worried about doing it in .Net since it has unsigned data types and SHL/SHR.